# How to solve TypeError: arr[Symbol.iterator] is not a function in my React project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am encountering this error while following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hT3j87FMR6M). I have so far followed his code exactly but he does not get this error. I am at 2:09:30 in the tutorial.

I've looked through all my hooks and all the variables and types seem to be correct. I thought it might be an error with `setSelectedProject()` but this line of investigation did not prove fruitful. `allProjects` and `projects` are definitely arrays...

IndividualProject.js

```
export const IndividualProject = ({ project }) => {
  const [showConfirm, setShowConfirm] = useState(false);
  const [projects, setProjects] = useProjectsValue();
  const { setSelectedProject } = useSelectedProjectValue();
  console.log("Projects: ", projects);
  const deleteProject = docId => {
    firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("projects")
      .doc(docId)
      .delete()
      .then(() => {
        setProjects([...projects]);
        console.log("Projects from IndividualProject: ", project);
        setSelectedProject("Inbox");
      });
  };
...
```

src/hooks/Index.js

```
export const useProjects = () => {
  const [projects, setProjects] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("projects")
      .where("userId", "==", "PO1n5mxjYYpcnq9joPZl")
      .orderBy("projectId")
      .get()
      .then(snapshot => {
        const allProjects = snapshot.docs.map(project => ({
          ...project.data(),
          docId: project.id
        }));
        console.log(typeof allProjects);
        if (JSON.stringify(allProjects) !== JSON.stringify(projects)) {
          setProjects(allProjects);
        }
      });
  }, [projects]);
  return { projects, setProjects };
};
```

Projects.js

```
export const Projects = ({ activeValue = null }) => {
  const [active, setActive] = useState(activeValue);
  const { setSelectedProject } = useSelectedProjectValue();
  const { projects } = useProjectsValue();
  return (
    projects &&
    projects.map(project => (
      <li
        key={project.projectId}
        data-doc-id={project.docId}
        data-testid="project-action"
        className={
          active === project.projectId
            ? "active sidebar__project"
            : "sidebar__project"
        }
        onClick={() => {
          setActive(project.projectId);
          setSelectedProject(project.projectId);
        }}
      >
        <IndividualProject project={project} />
      </li>
    ))
  );
};
```

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2w1Y.png) is a full screenshot of the error output upon compiling.

Comment: Can you show the code where you call `IndividualProject`? I have a wild guess that that might be the problem, if the line that throws the error is actually at the line shown in the stack trace. Or, it may not be that - what does logging Projects give you, when you do `console.log("Projects: ", projects);`?

Comment: done, see edited post. Also, that particular `console.log()` does not appear to be reached for some reason (outputs nothing)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The way you're consuming the return values in the `IndividualProject` component of your `useSelectedProjectValue` custom hook is wrong:

`const [projects, setProjects] = useProjectsValue();`

should be

`const { projects, setProjects } = useProjectsValue();`

React uses [array destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) e. g. for their `useState`, but your `useSelectedProjectValue` hook is rather returning an object and not an array, so you have to consume it in the components with object desctructuring. Or change the return value of the custom hook to an array.

If you want to learn more about this topic I recommend reading [Kent C. Dodds'](https://stackoverflow.com/users/971592/kentcdodds) blog:  https://kentcdodds.com/blog/react-hooks-array-destructuring-fundamentals

Comment: Thank you, this has to be it. Will mark as answer when I’m able to test it.

Comment: Thanks, I had typo and it cost me a hour to find I used [] instead of {}.